# How to connect two neural networks in Keras

Tags: keras, neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have a question about Keras and deep neural networks. I don't know if it is possible.

Structure:
"Neural network 1" gets the input "Input1" and computes the output "output 1". The inputs of "neural network 2" are "output 1" and "Input 1".

Could you please tell me if this is possible and how i can build a neural network like this with Kers?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is possible by using [`Concatenate`](https://keras.io/layers/merge/#concatenate) layer and [`Model`](https://keras.io/models/model/):

```
input_1 = Input(shape=(10,))
output_1 = Dense(1)(input_1)
input_2 = Input(shape=(5,))
concat_2 = Concatenate()([output_1, input_2])
output_2 = Dense(1)(concat_2)
model = Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=[output_2])
```

Complete example:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Concatenate, Dense, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

import numpy as np

x1 = np.random.normal(size=(1000, 10))
x2 = np.random.normal(size=(1000, 5))
y = (
    x1.mean(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    + x2.mean(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    + np.random.normal(scale=0.05, size=(1000, 1))
)

input_1 = Input(shape=(10,))
output_1 = Dense(1)(input_1)
input_2 = Input(shape=(5,))
concat_2 = Concatenate()([output_1, input_2])
output_2 = Dense(1)(concat_2)
model = Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=[output_2])

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd')
hist = model.fit([x1, x2], y, epochs=500)
```